# Crystal Reports (10) - Records go to next page

Tags: crystal-reports

If a full record doesn't fit on 1 page, it goes on to the next. Which property can I set to prevent that from happening? If it doesn't fit, I would like it to start its own page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a property in the section expert called "New Page After" or "Keep together".